# Populate Create By field from Assigned to User field

Tags: apex, trigger

I don't even know where to begin with this trigger... I need a trigger that can overwrite the Created By field in my Task, with the Assigned to User (picklist) field I created. I've opened the Created By field to be audited, so I can make changes.

Answer (score 3):

> I've opened the Created By field to be audited, so I can make changes.

Not in a trigger, I'm afraid. This permission is [API only](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_general_audit_fields_inactive_owners.htm):

> Set audit fields, such as Created By and Last Modified By, when you create a record **(API only)**.

Emphasis mine. You can set the audit fields when performing data loads via the API (using an application like Data Loader), but not in Apex. See also [Enable 'Create Audit Fields'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213290&language=en_US&type=1)
.

Comment: Can you please expand on the API only comment? Do I need to contact Salesforce to open this option up?

Comment: @SabrinaBokhari As far as I'm aware, you can't. I don't believe it is possible to set audit fields, such as `CreatedById`, in Apex, full stop.

Comment: That's a real bummer. Thanks, David. The user alias name is not enabling our Platform users to view their tasks, since they were created by another user (i.e., not the assigned user, rather the assigner...) This is so frustrating

Comment: @SabrinaBokhari That sounds like it might be a bit of an x-y problem. If you are interested in adding some more detail and maybe screenshots to your question (I'm not sure I totally follow) I would be happy to propose any alternate solution that might come up.